# How to send data from back-end to google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to send e-commerce related data to Google Tag Manager instead of doing it on client side. This will allow me to track the data better. I've been looking at these docs, https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v1/reference, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do a POST request with event data to a tag.

Is there a way through google tag manager or google analytics to send data directly to tags?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is something like `Server-side container`.

It will allow you to post the request and it will bypass the data to other destinations.

The document you are looking at is the API to manage the Google Tag Manager. Not sending the data to it.

[Server-side Container Doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side)